# How to change col-sm (bootstrap) parent elemtn background-color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need a help

i failed to change background color for bootstrap parent element using css

this is my html code

```
    <div class="body-panel">
            <div class="col-sm-4 left-guest">
                testing
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 right-guest">

            </div>

    </div>
```

this is my css

```
.body-panel{
  color: blue;
  background-color: red;
}
.left-guest{
  border: dotted 1px black;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
.right-guest{
  border: dotted 1px black;
  min-height: 1000px;
}
```

but background-color at class body-panel is not working, and color is working

can someone help me?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.body-panel` has zero height due to the floated children (`col-sm-8`)

You need to clear the floats by either giving `.body-panel` a `row` class or a `clearfix` class, both of which are built in bootstrap helper classes.

```
<div class="body-panel row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 left-guest">
    testing
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 right-guest">

  </div>

</div>

<div class="body-panel clearfix">
  <div class="col-sm-4 left-guest">
    testing
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8 right-guest">

  </div>

</div>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://www.bootply.com/QPLVzFmbYO)

Answer (score 1):

Give body-panel overflow:hidden or even better, a row class.

This is because col classes from bootstrap are floated and as such parent element does not take them into account for height, so your body-panel has no height amd even though it applies background color, you don't see it.

I strongly suggest giving it a row class, as that' s a proper way to use bootstrap grid classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to achieve this scenario

please try this to change background color of parent div.

**

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".left-guest").parent().css("background-color", "yellow");
    });
</script>
```

**